# Blank space when soft-keyboard opens in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to use

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustReszize"
```

for detecting Soft Keyboard changes i.e when it opens/closes.

My problem is that when I do this I see a blank space for a split second as the view is first re-sized and then the keyboard opens.

Is there any way to avoid this other then adding a background image to the window?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to escape this.